# Unable to identify java object in uft

Tags: java, uft14

Java identification issue using uft
I am unable to spy the object of java application using uft
One old script which is created by someone from different machine using different uft version, it is working 
But any java objects I am unable to add from my uft
I have selected java add in also
Pls help me with the solution 
Do I need to install java also in my machine?